# Does every transaction creates a new block in blockchain?

Tags: python, blockchain

```
class Block:
   def __init__(self, index, transactions, previous_hash):
        self.index = index
        self.transactions = transactions
        self.previous_hash = previous_hash
        self.timestamp = time()

class BlockChain:
    self.chain = []

    def new_block(self, transactions):
        pass
```

lets say I make new a transaction `{'sender': 'bob', 'receiver': 'alice', 'amount': 2}`

will this transaction create a new block in the chain (i.e. `self.chain.append(new_block_which_has_above_transaction`)

or will it get last block in the chain (i.e. `len(self.chain)-1`) and modify the `self.transactions` of this block.

https://hackernoon.com/learn-blockchains-by-building-one-117428612f46
In this article, author is using `self.transactions` as a list and thats where I'm getting confused.

As per my understanding, every new transaction will create a new block with that transaction and that block will be appended to blockchain. if some one mine a new block, few coins will be awarded to miner as a transaction.
is that correct flow? or can a block has multiple transactions? if yes -

- 1) should a genesis block has multiple transactions?

  2) what if two nodes have different chain(I mean we need to resolve
  using consensus algorithm) but meanwhile if that node process a
  transaction then hash of that block would be changed and then what would happen to neighbour node's chain?

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin puts a cap of 2,400 transactions on each of their blocks, but not all blocks have this many. People broadcast transactions to miners and miners put transactions into blocks and distribute them.

As for your question:

1. The [website](https://hackernoon.com/learn-blockchains-by-building-one-117428612f46) you linked to says that blocks should be **immutable**, so you shouldn't append a new transaction onto a block's list. Also, this would change the value of the hash you need to find to validate the block.
2. It is up to you how many transactions you want per block, one or multiple. What I would do is gather the non-chained transactions, put them into a block and append that new block to the chain.

Comment: ```The website you linked to says that blocks should be immutable,``` so how should I append a new transaction?

How do you gather non-chained transactions and store? do you collect all transactions happened in an hour and store it temporary and after an hour you create a new block and put all transaction in it?

Comment: Yes. You gather transactions, then after an hour, group them together into a block